# How to solve DateTime exception when using a Flutter model

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm receiving data via an API and storing it in a Hive box within my mobile application.  An exception is being thrown on a DateTime field.

My raw data from the API response:

```
{"pointOfServiceNo":"3","pointOfServiceName":"DEANO POS 2","pointOfServiceDescription":"DEANO POS 2","pointOfServiceOrderingGroupNo":"113-1","orders":[{"orderType":"inventory","orderDate":"2022-12-08","deliveryDate":"2022-12-08"}
```

The exception is:

```
Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime?')
```

This is my Model method:

```
List<Orders> ordersListFromJson(String val) => List<Orders>.from(
json.decode(val)['orders'].map((val) => Orders.ordersInfofromJson(val)));

@HiveType(typeId: 2)
class Orders extends HiveObject {
@HiveField(0)
String? orderType;
@HiveField(1)
DateTime? orderDate;
@HiveField(2)
DateTime? deliveryDate;
@HiveField(3)
List<Articles>? articles;

Orders({this.orderType, this.orderDate, this.deliveryDate, this.articles});

factory Orders.ordersInfofromJson(Map<String, dynamic> orders) => Orders(
  orderType: orders['orderType'],
  orderDate: orders[DateTime.tryParse('orderDate')],
  deliveryDate: orders[DateTime.tryParse('deliveryDate')],
  articles: List<Articles>.from(orders['articles']
      .map((articles) => Articles.articlesfromJson(articles))));
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing the data received in your json for the fields orderDate and deliveryDate. Try this way:

```
factory Orders.ordersInfofromJson(Map<String, dynamic> orders) => Orders(
orderType: orders['orderType'],
orderDate: DateTime.tryParse(orders['orderDate']),
deliveryDate: DateTime.tryParse(orders['deliveryDate']),
articles: List<Articles>.from(orders['articles']
.map((articles) => Articles.articlesfromJson(articles))));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked an absolute treat. Much appreciated.